# Java datePicker get value

Tags: java

I have a problem. I can't get the value. Help me please. How can I get a date with  `datePicker`. Or how must I get string variable.

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("text.today", "Today");
p.put("text.month", "Month");
p.put("text.year", "Year");

JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model,p);
datePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
datePanel.setBounds(900, 30, 300, 200);
topRightPanel.add(datePanel);

JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new Formated());
topRightPanel.add(datePicker);

System.out.println(datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText());
```

Comment: Where does this `JDatePickerImpl` come from? I'm sure `Formated` is specific to your project 'cos it has a typo in it.

Comment: @TamasRev
I use JDatePickerImpl becouse i want print the select date , i dont know how  must do it . Class Formated , do date format , i saw this Class in the sites about JDatePanelImpl . http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-use-jdatepicker-to-display-calendar-component

Comment: @Vitalii the link in your comment literally shows how to get the `Date` object from a JDatePickerImpl

Comment: @Vitalii What do you mean 'nothing happens'?

Comment: @lucasvw  It mean ,i can print the current day but not the one that  I selected .And it is problem. If i use 
 Date selectedDates = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();  selectedDates is null

Answer (score 0):

This example may be help to you,you can add jcalendar-1.4.jar to your porject library folder.then this will work, 
and by using SimpleDateFormat command you can use any date format,

```
  JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();// 
  [JDateChooser look like this][1]

  SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date todayDate = new Date();//local date time'

  String choosedate = sdft.format(chooser.getDate());//select date
  String today = sdft.format(todayDate);//local date
```

---

Comment: how i can use it in datePanel  ? i can print current day without chooser .

Comment: I understand you , but i dont understand how it can help me becouse i can print 
 current date  and no sense to do new Calendar. And i can't print the date what i choose in datePanel . Or i cant make String variable with date in dataPicker !

Comment: I tried but nothing happened .... I dont know where my mistake.
String selectDate = datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText();
System.out.println(selectDate);

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
* and open the template in the editor.  */ package javaapplication11;

import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addMouseListener; import java.awt.Dimension; import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; import java.awt.event.ActionListener; import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter; import java.awt.event.MouseEvent; import java.text.ParseException; import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Calendar; import java.util.Properties; import javax.swing.JButton; import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter; import javax.swing.JFrame; import javax.swing.JPanel; import org.jdatepicker.JDatePanel; import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePanelImpl; import org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl; import org.jdatepicker.impl.UtilDateModel;

/**  *  * @author HPkavin  */ public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
    private JDatePickerImpl datePicker;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame a = new JFrame();
        a.setSize(500, 500);
        JPanel topRightPanel = new JPanel();
        a.add(topRightPanel);
        JButton GetDateButton = new JButton("Get date");
        topRightPanel.add(GetDateButton);
        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("text.today", "Today");
        p.put("text.month", "Month");
        p.put("text.year", "Year");

        JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
        datePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        datePanel.setBounds(900, 30, 300, 200);
        topRightPanel.add(datePanel);

        JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
        topRightPanel.add(datePicker);
        a.setVisible(true);
        datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().setText("2017-06-2");//you can use current date also (answer 1 )
        System.out.println(datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText());

        GetDateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(datePicker.getJFormattedTextField().getText());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if (value != null) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
            return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

Check this class,I implemented, I think this will help you definitely,

Comment: can i do it without button ? I make mouse listener with datePicker or data Panel but it is not work correctly